# Accessing NSApplicationScriptsDirectory with NSFileManager in sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm having a bit of trouble accessing the default folder for application scripts using this code (which I think is the right way to do it):

```
NSError* error;
NSURL* scriptsFolderURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory: NSApplicationScriptsDirectory inDomain: NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL: nil create: YES error: &error];

NSLog(@"%@", scriptsFolderURL);
NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
```

The problem is that both NSLog calls print `(null)`, meaning I'm not getting anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get for the Error if you just `NSLog( @"%@", error)`?

Comment: Are you sure your running in the sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I checked with Activity Monitor

Comment: Check your `Info.plist`.   I tried a couple of tests here, and inside and outside of the sandbox, I still get a good URL, but it depends on the app Bundle Identifier in the Info.plist.  If I compile and run a unit test with the same code, it results in the same failure mode as you're getting (`nil`,`nil`).

Comment: I just remembered since this seemed like a new API it might be 10.8 only. And it is. And I'm running 10.7. That... might have something to do with the problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have a valid `Info.plist` containing a valid Application Bundle ID and are running under OS X 10.8, this should work fine.

However, I can confirm that it isn't uncommon for the API to return nil with a nil error, which is a bit outside of the API contract.

Comment: Well, I'm going to have to get 10.8 anyways, so this might be a good time... Thanks for your help

Comment: Odd. I am testing on 10.8.2 and I have the issue - getting nil everywhere. My app is not sandboxed, though - that's not a requirement for this to work, is it?

Comment: Alright - turns out that this works really only in sandboxed apps. Meaning that for my hybrid app, I'll have to use a different way to run my scripts when not sandboxed. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

The comment for *NSApplicationScriptsDirectory* is as follows:

> // location of the user scripts folder for the calling application
>   (~/Library/Application Scripts/code-signing-id)

The code-signing-id gives the hint that you HAVE TO enable code-signing. As soon as you enable code-signing you'll receive a proper URL.